# Dynamically add new key to object after filling form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-admin

I am using `react-admin` framework and I am trying to add new key to my object. The name of the key should be the value that will be filled by the user using `TextInput`. 
This is the object:
[image: fugly screen shot of text]

I want to add the new key on the same level as is `E111`. So far I have tried to add the key using `SimpleForm`, but best I could do is `"":"E222"`. The inserted value is not the name of the key, but its value. Full path to the object is `this.props.record.tiles.Main.widgets[somekey]`.

So far I have simply tried this:

```
<SimpleForm {...this.props} toolbar={null}>
    <TextInput source='tiles.Main.widgets[]' label="Widget Key" style={{ width: '150px' }}/>
</SimpleForm>
```

But as I said with no luck.

Any suggestions how can I add a new key to object?

Comment: widgets.E11.newkey  = 'new_value'

Comment: Or `widgets.E11['newkey'] = 'new_value'` or `widgets['E11']['newkey'] = 'new_value'`

Comment: Im not sure that I understand how is that supposed to work. User should enter the name of the key to the input and then the key should be saved and added to the object.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the data from text input into the widgets like this.

```
widgets['newkey'] = 'new value'
```